# How can you tell a field name on a view of an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to web programming. I have an MVC application that I want to edit a field on the view. I understand the layout of the URL is {'ClassName' minus Controller keyword/'MethodName'} I don't get how to find the view that I'm looking at though. F12 dev tools don't work worth anything for this either. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in all versions of Visual Studio, but right click in the method on the controller and select "Go to View" at the top of the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

It uses a conventions based approach for view location. By default it should be in the views folder. For example if your controller name is HomeController and your action name is Index then the corresponding view is ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the controller Action method, in the options listed you can choose 'Go To View'. This will take you to the view code of the Action of respective controller